# Insert Popup message programmatically using leaflet js

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having a difficult time trying to figure out how I can display the marker with a pop up message programmatically using `leaftlet` js.

The class `country-pop-up-message` is the pop up message I want to be displayed for each marker when looped.

```
<ul class="countries">
    <li  class="country">
        <span class="country-name">Philippines</span>
        <div class="country-pop-up-message">
            <h2 class="population">Population: 200</h2>
            <p class="description">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</p>

        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="country">
        <span class="country-name">Brunei</span>
        <div class="country-pop-up-message">
            <h2 class="population">Population: 200</h2>
            <p class="description">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</p>

        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="country">
        <span class="country-name">Malaysia</span>
        <div class="country-pop-up-message">
            <h2 class="population">Population: 300</h2>
            <p class="description">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</p>

        </div>
    </li>

</ul>
```

```js
       var map = L.map('mapid', {

            fullscreenControl: {
                pseudoFullscreen: false // if true, fullscreen to page width and height
            },
            
        }).setView([0,0], 3);

        map.createPane('labels');
        map.getPane('labels').style.zIndex = 650;
        map.getPane('labels').style.pointerEvents = 'none';

        var positron = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                noWrap: true,
                maxZoom : 15
        }).addTo(map);

        var positronLabels = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_only_labels/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                pane: 'labels',
                noWrap: true,
                maxZoom : 3
        }).addTo(map);


        var southWest = L.latLng(-89.98155760646617, -180),
            northEast = L.latLng(89.99346179538875, 180),
            bounds = L.latLngBounds(southWest, northEast);

        map.setMaxBounds(bounds);
        map.on('drag', function() {
            map.panInsideBounds(bounds, { animate: false });
        });


        geocoder = new L.Control.Geocoder.Nominatim();

        var countries = [];
        var markers = [];

        var markerCluster = L.markerClusterGroup({ 
            spiderfyOnMaxZoom: false, 
            showCoverageOnHover: false,
            // zoomToBoundsOnClick: false 
        });



        $('.countries > .country > .country-name').each(function() {
            countries.push([
                $(this).text()                
            ]);
        });

    

        for(var i = 0; i < countries.length; i++) {
            
            geocoder.geocode(countries[i], function(results) {   
                console.log(countries[i]); 
                var latLng = new L.LatLng(results[0].center.lat, results[0].center.lng);
                marker = L.marker(latLng);

  
                markers.push(marker);
                markerCluster.addLayer(marker);
            });
        }

        markerCluster.on('clusterclick', function (a) {
        });
        map.addLayer(markerCluster);
```

```css
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 font-size: 100%;
 font: inherit;
 vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
 display: block;
}
body {
 line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
 list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
 quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
 content: '';
 content: none;
}
table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border-spacing: 0;
}

/* required styles */

.leaflet-pane,
.leaflet-tile,
.leaflet-marker-icon,
.leaflet-marker-shadow,
.leaflet-tile-container,
.leaflet-pane > svg,
.leaflet-pane > canvas,
.leaflet-zoom-box,
.leaflet-image-layer,
.leaflet-layer {
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 }
.leaflet-container {
 overflow: hidden;
 }
.leaflet-tile,
.leaflet-marker-icon,
.leaflet-marker-shadow {
 -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
         user-select: none;
   -webkit-user-drag: none;
 }
/* Safari renders non-retina tile on retina better with this, but Chrome is worse */
.leaflet-safari .leaflet-tile {
 image-rendering: -webkit-optimize-contrast;
 }
/* hack that prevents hw layers "stretching" when loading new tiles */
.leaflet-safari .leaflet-tile-container {
 width: 1600px;
 height: 1600px;
 -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
 }
.leaflet-marker-icon,
.leaflet-marker-shadow {
 display: block;
 }
/* .leaflet-container svg: reset svg max-width decleration shipped in Joomla! (joomla.org) 3.x */
/* .leaflet-container img: map is broken in FF if you have max-width: 100% on tiles */
.leaflet-container .leaflet-overlay-pane svg,
.leaflet-container .leaflet-marker-pane img,
.leaflet-container .leaflet-shadow-pane img,
.leaflet-container .leaflet-tile-pane img,
.leaflet-container img.leaflet-image-layer,
.leaflet-container .leaflet-tile {
 max-width: none !important;
 max-height: none !important;
 }

.leaflet-container.leaflet-touch-zoom {
 -ms-touch-action: pan-x pan-y;
 touch-action: pan-x pan-y;
 }
.leaflet-container.leaflet-touch-drag {
 -ms-touch-action: pinch-zoom;
 /* Fallback for FF which doesn't support pinch-zoom */
 touch-action: none;
 touch-action: pinch-zoom;
}
.leaflet-container.leaflet-touch-drag.leaflet-touch-zoom {
 -ms-touch-action: none;
 touch-action: none;
}
.leaflet-container {
 -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}
.leaflet-container a {
 -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(51, 181, 229, 0.4);
}
.leaflet-tile {
 filter: inherit;
 visibility: hidden;
 }
.leaflet-tile-loaded {
 visibility: inherit;
 }
.leaflet-zoom-box {
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
      box-sizing: border-box;
 z-index: 800;
 }
/* workaround for https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=888319 */
.leaflet-overlay-pane svg {
 -moz-user-select: none;
 }

.leaflet-pane         { z-index: 400; }

.leaflet-tile-pane    { z-index: 200; }
.leaflet-overlay-pane { z-index: 400; }
.leaflet-shadow-pane  { z-index: 500; }
.leaflet-marker-pane  { z-index: 600; }
.leaflet-tooltip-pane   { z-index: 650; }
.leaflet-popup-pane   { z-index: 700; }

.leaflet-map-pane canvas { z-index: 100; }
.leaflet-map-pane svg    { z-index: 200; }

.leaflet-vml-shape {
 width: 1px;
 height: 1px;
 }
.lvml {
 behavior: url(#default#VML);
 display: inline-block;
 position: absolute;
 }


/* control positioning */

.leaflet-control {
 position: relative;
 z-index: 800;
 pointer-events: visiblePainted; /* IE 9-10 doesn't have auto */
 pointer-events: auto;
 }
.leaflet-top,
.leaflet-bottom {
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 1000;
 pointer-events: none;
 }
.leaflet-top {
 top: 0;
 }
.leaflet-right {
 right: 0;
 }
.leaflet-bottom {
 bottom: 0;
 }
.leaflet-left {
 left: 0;
 }
.leaflet-control {
 float: left;
 clear: both;
 }
.leaflet-right .leaflet-control {
 float: right;
 }
.leaflet-top .leaflet-control {
 margin-top: 10px;
 }
.leaflet-bottom .leaflet-control {
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 }
.leaflet-left .leaflet-control {
 margin-left: 10px;
 }
.leaflet-right .leaflet-control {
 margin-right: 10px;
 }


/* zoom and fade animations */

.leaflet-fade-anim .leaflet-tile {
 will-change: opacity;
 }
.leaflet-fade-anim .leaflet-popup {
 opacity: 0;
 -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s linear;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s linear;
         transition: opacity 0.2s linear;
 }
.leaflet-fade-anim .leaflet-map-pane .leaflet-popup {
 opacity: 1;
 }
.leaflet-zoom-animated {
 -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
     -ms-transform-origin: 0 0;
         transform-origin: 0 0;
 }
.leaflet-zoom-anim .leaflet-zoom-animated {
 will-change: transform;
 }
.leaflet-zoom-anim .leaflet-zoom-animated {
 -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.25s cubic-bezier(0,0,0.25,1);
    -moz-transition:    -moz-transform 0.25s cubic-bezier(0,0,0.25,1);
         transition:         transform 0.25s cubic-bezier(0,0,0.25,1);
 }
.leaflet-zoom-anim .leaflet-tile,
.leaflet-pan-anim .leaflet-tile {
 -webkit-transition: none;
    -moz-transition: none;
         transition: none;
 }

.leaflet-zoom-anim .leaflet-zoom-hide {
 visibility: hidden;
 }


/* cursors */

.leaflet-interactive {
 cursor: pointer;
 }
.leaflet-grab {
 cursor: -webkit-grab;
 cursor:    -moz-grab;
 cursor:         grab;
 }
.leaflet-crosshair,
.leaflet-crosshair .leaflet-interactive {
 cursor: crosshair;
 }
.leaflet-popup-pane,
.leaflet-control {
 cursor: auto;
 }
.leaflet-dragging .leaflet-grab,
.leaflet-dragging .leaflet-grab .leaflet-interactive,
.leaflet-dragging .leaflet-marker-draggable {
 cursor: move;
 cursor: -webkit-grabbing;
 cursor:    -moz-grabbing;
 cursor:         grabbing;
 }

/* marker & overlays interactivity */
.leaflet-marker-icon,
.leaflet-marker-shadow,
.leaflet-image-layer,
.leaflet-pane > svg path,
.leaflet-tile-container {
 pointer-events: none;
 }

.leaflet-marker-icon.leaflet-interactive,
.leaflet-image-layer.leaflet-interactive,
.leaflet-pane > svg path.leaflet-interactive {
 pointer-events: visiblePainted; /* IE 9-10 doesn't have auto */
 pointer-events: auto;
 }

/* visual tweaks */

.leaflet-container {
 background: #ddd;
 outline: 0;
 }
.leaflet-container a {
 color: #0078A8;
 }
.leaflet-container a.leaflet-active {
 outline: 2px solid orange;
 }
.leaflet-zoom-box {
 border: 2px dotted #38f;
 background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
 }


/* general typography */
.leaflet-container {
 font: 12px/1.5 "Helvetica Neue", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 }


/* general toolbar styles */

.leaflet-bar {
 box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.65);
 border-radius: 4px;
 }
.leaflet-bar a,
.leaflet-bar a:hover {
 background-color: #fff;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
 width: 26px;
 height: 26px;
 line-height: 26px;
 display: block;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: black;
 }
.leaflet-bar a,
.leaflet-control-layers-toggle {
 background-position: 50% 50%;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 display: block;
 }
.leaflet-bar a:hover {
 background-color: #f4f4f4;
 }
.leaflet-bar a:first-child {
 border-top-left-radius: 4px;
 border-top-right-radius: 4px;
 }
.leaflet-bar a:last-child {
 border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
 border-bottom: none;
 }
.leaflet-bar a.leaflet-disabled {
 cursor: default;
 background-color: #f4f4f4;
 color: #bbb;
 }

.leaflet-touch .leaflet-bar a {
 width: 30px;
 height: 30px;
 line-height: 30px;
 }
.leaflet-touch .leaflet-bar a:first-child {
 border-top-left-radius: 2px;
 border-top-right-radius: 2px;
 }
.leaflet-touch .leaflet-bar a:last-child {
 border-bottom-left-radius: 2px;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 2px;
 }

/* zoom control */

.leaflet-control-zoom-in,
.leaflet-control-zoom-out {
 font: bold 18px 'Lucida Console', Monaco, monospace;
 text-indent: 1px;
 }

.leaflet-touch .leaflet-control-zoom-in, .leaflet-touch .leaflet-control-zoom-out  {
 font-size: 22px;
 }


/* layers control */

.leaflet-control-layers {
 box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
 background: #fff;
 border-radius: 5px;
 }
.leaflet-control-layers-toggle {
 background-image: url(images/layers.png);
 width: 36px;
 height: 36px;
 }
.leaflet-retina .leaflet-control-layers-toggle {
 background-image: url(images/layers-2x.png);
 background-size: 26px 26px;
 }
.leaflet-touch .leaflet-control-layers-toggle {
 width: 44px;
 height: 44px;
 }
.leaflet-control-layers .leaflet-control-layers-list,
.leaflet-control-layers-expanded .leaflet-control-layers-toggle {
 display: none;
 }
.leaflet-control-layers-expanded .leaflet-control-layers-list {
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 }
.leaflet-control-layers-expanded {
 padding: 6px 10px 6px 6px;
 color: #333;
 background: #fff;
 }
.leaflet-control-layers-scrollbar {
 overflow-y: scroll;
 overflow-x: hidden;
 padding-right: 5px;
 }
.leaflet-control-layers-selector {
 margin-top: 2px;
 position: relative;
 top: 1px;
 }
.leaflet-control-layers label {
 display: block;
 }
.leaflet-control-layers-separator {
 height: 0;
 border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
 margin: 5px -10px 5px -6px;
 }

/* Default icon URLs */
.leaflet-default-icon-path {
 background-image: url(images/marker-icon.png);
 }


/* attribution and scale controls */

.leaflet-container .leaflet-control-attribution {
 background: #fff;
 background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
 margin: 0;
 }
.leaflet-control-attribution,
.leaflet-control-scale-line {
 padding: 0 5px;
 color: #333;
 }
.leaflet-control-attribution a {
 text-decoration: none;
 }
.leaflet-control-attribution a:hover {
 text-decoration: underline;
 }
.leaflet-container .leaflet-control-attribution,
.leaflet-container .leaflet-control-scale {
 font-size: 11px;
 }
.leaflet-left .leaflet-control-scale {
 margin-left: 5px;
 }
.leaflet-bottom .leaflet-control-scale {
 margin-bottom: 5px;
 }
.leaflet-control-scale-line {
 border: 2px solid #777;
 border-top: none;
 line-height: 1.1;
 padding: 2px 5px 1px;
 font-size: 11px;
 white-space: nowrap;
 overflow: hidden;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
      box-sizing: border-box;

 background: #fff;
 background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
 }
.leaflet-control-scale-line:not(:first-child) {
 border-top: 2px solid #777;
 border-bottom: none;
 margin-top: -2px;
 }
.leaflet-control-scale-line:not(:first-child):not(:last-child) {
 border-bottom: 2px solid #777;
 }

.leaflet-touch .leaflet-control-attribution,
.leaflet-touch .leaflet-control-layers,
.leaflet-touch .leaflet-bar {
 box-shadow: none;
 }
.leaflet-touch .leaflet-control-layers,
.leaflet-touch .leaflet-bar {
 border: 2px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 background-clip: padding-box;
 }


/* popup */

.leaflet-popup {
 position: absolute;
 text-align: center;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 }
.leaflet-popup-content-wrapper {
 padding: 1px;
 text-align: left;
 border-radius: 12px;
 }
.leaflet-popup-content {
 margin: 13px 19px;
 line-height: 1.4;
 }
.leaflet-popup-content p {
 margin: 18px 0;
 }
.leaflet-popup-tip-container {
 width: 40px;
 height: 20px;
 position: absolute;
 left: 50%;
 margin-left: -20px;
 overflow: hidden;
 pointer-events: none;
 }
.leaflet-popup-tip {
 width: 17px;
 height: 17px;
 padding: 1px;

 margin: -10px auto 0;

 -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
     -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
         transform: rotate(45deg);
 }
.leaflet-popup-content-wrapper,
.leaflet-popup-tip {
 background: white;
 color: #333;
 box-shadow: 0 3px 14px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
 }
.leaflet-container a.leaflet-popup-close-button {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
 padding: 4px 4px 0 0;
 border: none;
 text-align: center;
 width: 18px;
 height: 14px;
 font: 16px/14px Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;
 color: #c3c3c3;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-weight: bold;
 background: transparent;
 }
.leaflet-container a.leaflet-popup-close-button:hover {
 color: #999;
 }
.leaflet-popup-scrolled {
 overflow: auto;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
 border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
 }

.leaflet-oldie .leaflet-popup-content-wrapper {
 zoom: 1;
 }
.leaflet-oldie .leaflet-popup-tip {
 width: 24px;
 margin: 0 auto;

 -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=0.70710678, M12=0.70710678, M21=-0.70710678, M22=0.70710678)";
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=0.70710678, M12=0.70710678, M21=-0.70710678, M22=0.70710678);
 }
.leaflet-oldie .leaflet-popup-tip-container {
 margin-top: -1px;
 }

.leaflet-oldie .leaflet-control-zoom,
.leaflet-oldie .leaflet-control-layers,
.leaflet-oldie .leaflet-popup-content-wrapper,
.leaflet-oldie .leaflet-popup-tip {
 border: 1px solid #999;
 }


/* div icon */

.leaflet-div-icon {
 background: #fff;
 border: 1px solid #666;
 }


/* Tooltip */
/* Base styles for the element that has a tooltip */
.leaflet-tooltip {
 position: absolute;
 padding: 6px;
 background-color: #fff;
 border: 1px solid #fff;
 border-radius: 3px;
 color: #222;
 white-space: nowrap;
 -webkit-user-select: none;
 -moz-user-select: none;
 -ms-user-select: none;
 user-select: none;
 pointer-events: none;
 box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
 }
.leaflet-tooltip.leaflet-clickable {
 cursor: pointer;
 pointer-events: auto;
 }
.leaflet-tooltip-top:before,
.leaflet-tooltip-bottom:before,
.leaflet-tooltip-left:before,
.leaflet-tooltip-right:before {
 position: absolute;
 pointer-events: none;
 border: 6px solid transparent;
 background: transparent;
 content: "";
 }

/* Directions */

.leaflet-tooltip-bottom {
 margin-top: 6px;
}
.leaflet-tooltip-top {
 margin-top: -6px;
}
.leaflet-tooltip-bottom:before,
.leaflet-tooltip-top:before {
 left: 50%;
 margin-left: -6px;
 }
.leaflet-tooltip-top:before {
 bottom: 0;
 margin-bottom: -12px;
 border-top-color: #fff;
 }
.leaflet-tooltip-bottom:before {
 top: 0;
 margin-top: -12px;
 margin-left: -6px;
 border-bottom-color: #fff;
 }
.leaflet-tooltip-left {
 margin-left: -6px;
}
.leaflet-tooltip-right {
 margin-left: 6px;
}
.leaflet-tooltip-left:before,
.leaflet-tooltip-right:before {
 top: 50%;
 margin-top: -6px;
 }
.leaflet-tooltip-left:before {
 right: 0;
 margin-right: -12px;
 border-left-color: #fff;
 }
.leaflet-tooltip-right:before {
 left: 0;
 margin-left: -12px;
 border-right-color: #fff;
 }



html, body {
    width  : 100%;
    height : 100%;
}

.map-container {
    width : 100%;
    height : 100%;
    
}
```

```html
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.4/dist/leaflet.css"
  />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet.markercluster@1.4.1/dist/MarkerCluster.Default.css" />

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.4/dist/leaflet.js"
    ></script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBet5Wx-JdSc4cY4v4zR6_FIhYc2oWgTv4"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet-control-geocoder/dist/Control.Geocoder.js" ></script>
    <script src='https://unpkg.com/leaflet.gridlayer.googlemutant@latest/Leaflet.GoogleMutant.js'></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet.markercluster@1.4.1/dist/leaflet.markercluster-src.js"></script>
    
    <div class="map-container" id="mapid"></div>
    
            <ul class="countries">
            <li  class="country">
                <span class="country-name">Philippines</span>
                <div class="country-pop-up-message">
                    <h2 class="population">Population: 200</h2>
                    <p class="description">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</p>

                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="country">
                <span class="country-name">Brunei</span>
                <div class="country-pop-up-message">
                    <h2 class="population">Population: 200</h2>
                    <p class="description">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</p>

                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="country">
                <span class="country-name">Malaysia</span>
                <div class="country-pop-up-message">
                    <h2 class="population">Population: 300</h2>
                    <p class="description">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</p>

                </div>
            </li>

        </ul>
```